# Unit Testing component that depends on RouterExtensions from "nativescript-angular/router" for navigation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am writing unit test on a nativescript-angular component to test a number of things 1)Submit function for a login form and 2) router navigation/view after successful login.

In the component I am using `RouterExtensions` from `nativescript-angular/router` for navigation

In the component constructor i am initializing the component with default user credentials and passing the routerextension as an argument.

```
constructor(private page: Page,private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){
     this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
     this.user = new User();
     this.user.email = "dennis@gmail.com";
     this.user.password = "password";
 }
```

on successful logging i am  navigating the user to`home` page and the logic for that looks like this.

```
    submit(){
        if (!this.user.email || !this.user.password) {
            this.alert("Please provide both an email address and password.");
            return;
        }
        this.processing = true;
        if(this.isLoggingIn){
            this.login();
        }else{
            this.register();
        }

    }
    login() {
        console.log(this.user)
        if(this.user){
            this.processing = false;
            this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });
        }else{
            this.processing = false;
            this.alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.");
        }

    }
```

I am using mocha for testing and my unit test at the moment looks like this

```
var reflect = require("reflect-metadata");
var component = require("../app/login/login.component");

describe("Test for Login component", ()=>{
    var appComponent;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        appComponent = new component.LoginComponent();
    });

    it("Should Login User", ()=> {
        appComponent.submit();

        assert.equal(appComponent.user.email,"dennis@gmail.com")
        assert.equal(appComponent.user.password,"password")
    });

    it("Should navigate user to home page",()=>{
        // Logic for testing that the view is home page.
    })
});
```

On running the test I get this error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

I understand that this error is as a result of this line:
`this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });` in the `login()` method because on commenting it the test passes.

What I am not sure is how do I write unit test to test for both page routing and view that the user is at .How do i mock the navigation issue.Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: This is what I did ```let router = jasmine.createSpyObj("Router", ["navigate"]);``` then in the test function ```expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to solve this, in the test file

```
var reflect = require("reflect-metadata");
var component = require("../app/login/login.component");
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";


describe("Test for Login component", ()=>{
 let appComponent;
 let page = Page;
 let router = jasmine.createSpyObj("Router", ["navigate"]);
}

  beforeEach(()=>{

        appComponent = new component.LoginComponent(page,router);
    });

   it("Should Login User when login button is clicked", ()=> {
        appComponent.submit();
        expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });
    });
```